# Javascript filter with an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

Here's my code:

```
data = [
  {
    Company: "Company Name",
    Type: "MINING",
    Location: "Middle East"
  },
  {
    Company: "Company Name 2",
    Type: "DISTRIBUTION OUTLET",
    Location: "Europe"
  },
  ...
];
myfilter = [
  "REPROCESSING PLANT",
  "MINING",
  "PROCESSING PLANT/MINE",
  "DISTRIBUTION OUTLET"
];
var myresults = [];
results = data.filter(function(el) {
  if (myfilter.indexOf(el.Type) != -1 && myfilter.indexOf(el.Location) != -1) {
    return el;
  }
});

console.log(results);
```

(original: https://jsfiddle.net/rpsb8buh/4/)

Requirement :

i have a data Array and i want to filter them based on the following array filters, its working fine if use **Type** && **Location** together like this

```
myfilter = ['REPROCESSING PLANT','MINING','PROCESSING PLANT/MINE','DISTRIBUTION OUTLET','Europe'];
```

but if I pass filter like that without **Location** it wont work

```
myfilter = ['REPROCESSING PLANT','MINING','PROCESSING PLANT/MINE','DISTRIBUTION OUTLET'];
```

Comment: you probably want || instead of &&

Comment: Because `&&` match both conditions are true use with `||` instead of `&&`

Comment: || will show all the data so it wont filter it will combine all data

Answer (score 3):

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rpsb8buh/12/)

Because `&&` return only both conditions are true.
Better use with [`Array#includes()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiQztf30p_WAhVBM48KHVMIAZkQFggoMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fincludes&usg=AFQjCNH5UxAefwkcnRMTtq3VoGcYGJuHDg)

**Updated**

you should validate the array length after filtering.Then its empty you assign data array or filter with `type` matching array as your wish

```js
var data = [ { "Company": "Company Name", "Address": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet quaeque eruditi", "Telphone": "9714 883 7571", "Email": "Gma@emirates.net.ae", "Website": "www.emirates.net.au", "MarkerColor": 'pink', "Type": "MINING", "Location": "Middle East", "latitude": 25.856407, "longitude": 17.247047 }, { "Company": "Company Name 2", "Address": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vel no congue quaeque eruditi", "Telphone": "", "Email": "Gma@emirates.net.ae", "Website": "", "MarkerColor": 'brown', "Type": "DISTRIBUTION OUTLET", "Location": "Europe", "latitude": 45.526054, "longitude": 3.892456 }, { "Company": "Company Name 3", "Address": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vel no congue quaeque eruditi", "Telphone": "22115 48558", "Email": "Gma@emirates.net.ae", "Website": "", "MarkerColor": 'yellow', "Type": "REPROCESSING PLANT", "Location": "Middle East", "latitude": 20.526054, "longitude": 1.892456 }, { "Company": "Company Name 4", "Address": "", "Telphone": "221 981 558", "Email": "Gma@emirates.net.ae", "Website": "", "MarkerColor": 'light-pink', "Type": "PROCESSING PLANT/MINE", "Location": "Europe", "latitude": 48.526054, "longitude": 26.892456 }, { "Company": "Company Name 5", "Address": "", "Telphone": "111 922 252", "Email": "Gma@emirates.net.ae", "Website": "www.example.com", "MarkerColor": 'yellow', "Type": "REPROCESSING PLANT", "Location": "Middle East", "latitude": 32.526054, "longitude": 36.892456 }, { "Company": "Company Name 6", "Address": "", "Telphone": "4361 922 252", "Email": "Gma@emirates.net.ae", "Website": "www.example.com", "MarkerColor": 'yellow', "Type": "REPROCESSING PLANT", "Location": "Americas", "latitude": -32.526054, "longitude": -66.892456 }, { "Company": "Company Name 7", "Address": "", "Telphone": "4361 332 111", "Email": "Gma@emirates.net.ae", "Website": "www.ssaww.com", "MarkerColor": 'brown', "Type": "DISTRIBUTION OUTLET", "Location": "Middle East", "latitude": -32.526054, "longitude": 26.892456 }, { "Company": "Company Name 8", "Address": "", "Telphone": "221 981 558", "Email": "Gma@emirates.net.ae", "Website": "", "MarkerColor": 'light-pink', "Type": "PROCESSING PLANT/MINE", "Location": "Asia Pacific", "latitude": 18.526054, "longitude": 76.892456 }, { "Company": "Company Name 9", "Address": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet quaeque eruditi", "Telphone": "9714 883 7571", "Email": "Gma@emirates.net.ae", "Website": "www.emirates.net.au", "MarkerColor": 'pink', "Type": "MINING", "Location": "Middle East", "latitude": -5.856407, "longitude": 20.247047 }, { "Company": "Company Name 10", "Address": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet quaeque eruditi", "Telphone": "", "Email": "Gma@emirates.net.ae", "Website": "www.emirates.net.au", "MarkerColor": 'brown', "Type": "DISTRIBUTION OUTLET", "Location": "Asia Pacific", "latitude": -25.856407, "longitude": 120.247047 }, { "Company": "Company Name 11", "Address": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet quaeque eruditi", "Telphone": "", "Email": "Gma@emirates.net.ae", "Website": "www.emirates.net.au", "MarkerColor": 'yellow', "Type": "REPROCESSING PLANT", "Location": "Americas", "latitude": 55.856407, "longitude": -120.247047 }, { "Company": "Company Name 12", "Address": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet quaeque eruditi", "Telphone": "", "Email": "Gma@emirates.net.ae", "Website": "", "MarkerColor": 'pink', "Type": "MINING", "Location": "Americas", "latitude": 25.856407, "longitude": -100.247047 }, { "Company": "Company Name 13", "Address": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet quaeque eruditi", "Telphone": "", "Email": "Gma@emirates.net.ae", "Website": "", "MarkerColor": 'pink', "Type": "MINING", "Location": "Asia Pacific", "latitude": 4.062187, "longitude": 101.496645 }, { "Company": "Company Name 14", "Address": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet quaeque eruditi", "Telphone": "2233 65448 21", "Email": "Gma@emirates.net.ae", "Website": "", "MarkerColor": 'yellow', "Type": "REPROCESSING PLANT", "Location": "Asia Pacific", "latitude": 22.556300, "longitude": 113.916657 }, { "Company": "Company Name 15", "Address": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet quaeque eruditi", "Telphone": "2233 65448 21", "Email": "Gma@emirates.net.ae", "Website": "www.example.com", "MarkerColor": 'light-pink', "Type": "PROCESSING PLANT/MINE", "Location": "Americas", "latitude": 25.826347, "longitude": -80.207989 }, { "Company": "Company Name 16", "Address": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vel no congue quaeque eruditi", "Telphone": "", "Email": "Gma@emirates.net.ae", "Website": "", "MarkerColor": 'yellow', "Type": "REPROCESSING PLANT", "Location": "Europe", "latitude": 39.526054, "longitude": -3.892456 } ];

var  myfilter = ['REPROCESSING PLANT','MINING','PROCESSING PLANT/MINE','DISTRIBUTION OUTLET','Europe'];
var myresults= [];
 var results = data.filter(function(el){ 
             return myfilter.includes(el.Type) &&  myfilter.includes(el.Location)
    })
  
  if(results.length ==0 ){ //if array empty
  results = data.filter(function(el){ 
             return myfilter.includes(el.Type);//set  all matched type
  })
  //or if you need all 
  //assign
  //results = data
  }

console.log(results)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No..it works .. its show all the data.because type match with myfilter array .alter the myfilter array .you could see the changes in `console.log`.[see this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rpsb8buh/6/)

Comment: Thanks for your time, but it should only show data number 3 and 16 as these 2 only have Location : Europe, it cant show all the data with different locations

Comment: it's satisfied from your old rule  `&&`. https://jsfiddle.net/rpsb8buh/9/ . I mentioned my answer  without assigning location in  myfilter array it won't returning anything because it's not matching any value in my filter array

Comment: yeah, but if i pass the filters without the location it will return empty array while it should return all the data as all the data as the filters i put I.e
myfilter = ['REPROCESSING PLANT','MINING','PROCESSING PLANT/MINE','DISTRIBUTION OUTLET'];

Comment: ok, .i get the point.you should validate the array length after filtering. [see this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rpsb8buh/12/)

Comment: if i put myfilter = ['Europe']; it will give me empty array, while it should return 2 data which have Europe for location

Comment: Check one by one like this [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rpsb8buh/17/) . I think it's satisfied your expectation

Comment: Still not working, Thanks for your time i think i have something in mind to fix it, really appreciate you effort you have been very helpful thanks again

Answer (score 0):

This is your filter function:

```
if (myfilter.indexOf(el.Type) != -1 && myfilter.indexOf(el.Location) != -1)
```

The condition will be true if both type and location is present in myFilter.
If it is not your aim, maybe you can use an OR ( ||) like this:

```
if (myfilter.indexOf(el.Type) != -1 || myfilter.indexOf(el.Location) != -1)
```

This way the condition will be true if the type or the location (or both) is present.

Comment: || will show all the data so it wont filter it will combine all data

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but if nor the type nor the location is present than both boolean will be false therefore the whole expression will be false. So you won't get the data if both the type and the location is not present in myfilter.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

Working solution: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rpsb8buh/21/)

**With:** `Array#Filter` & `Array#Some`

*Example:*

```js
let data = [
{
        "Company": "Company Name",
        "Address": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet quaeque eruditi",
        "Telphone": "9714 883 7571",
        "Email": "Gma@emirates.net.ae",
        "Website": "www.emirates.net.au",
        "MarkerColor": 'pink',
        "Type": "MINING",
        "Location": "Middle East",
        "latitude": 25.856407,
        "longitude": 17.247047
    },
    {
        "Company": "Company Name 2",
        "Address": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vel no congue quaeque eruditi",
        "Telphone": "",
        "Email": "Gma@emirates.net.ae",
        "Website": "",
        "MarkerColor": 'brown',
        "Type": "DISTRIBUTION OUTLET",
        "Location": "Europe",
        "latitude": 45.526054,
        "longitude": 3.892456
    },
    {
        "Company": "Company Name 3",
        "Address": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vel no congue quaeque eruditi",
        "Telphone": "22115 48558",
        "Email": "Gma@emirates.net.ae",
        "Website": "",
        "MarkerColor": 'yellow',
        "Type": "REPROCESSING PLANT",
        "Location": "Middle East",
        "latitude": 20.526054,
        "longitude": 1.892456
    },
    {
        "Company": "Company Name 4",
        "Address": "",
        "Telphone": "221 981 558",
        "Email": "Gma@emirates.net.ae",
        "Website": "",
        "MarkerColor": 'light-pink',
        "Type": "PROCESSING PLANT/MINE",
        "Location": "Europe",
        "latitude": 48.526054,
        "longitude": 26.892456
    },
    {
        "Company": "Company Name 5",
        "Address": "",
        "Telphone": "111 922 252",
        "Email": "Gma@emirates.net.ae",
        "Website": "www.example.com",
        "MarkerColor": 'yellow',
        "Type": "REPROCESSING PLANT",
        "Location": "Middle East",
        "latitude": 32.526054,
        "longitude": 36.892456
    },
    {
        "Company": "Company Name 6",
        "Address": "",
        "Telphone": "4361 922 252",
        "Email": "Gma@emirates.net.ae",
        "Website": "www.example.com",
        "MarkerColor": 'yellow',
        "Type": "REPROCESSING PLANT",
        "Location": "Americas",
        "latitude": -32.526054,
        "longitude": -66.892456
    },
    {
        "Company": "Company Name 7",
        "Address": "",
        "Telphone": "4361 332 111",
        "Email": "Gma@emirates.net.ae",
        "Website": "www.ssaww.com",
        "MarkerColor": 'brown',
        "Type": "DISTRIBUTION OUTLET",
        "Location": "Middle East",
        "latitude": -32.526054,
        "longitude": 26.892456
    },
    {
        "Company": "Company Name 8",
        "Address": "",
        "Telphone": "221 981 558",
        "Email": "Gma@emirates.net.ae",
        "Website": "",
        "MarkerColor": 'light-pink',
        "Type": "PROCESSING PLANT/MINE",
        "Location": "Asia Pacific",
        "latitude": 18.526054,
        "longitude": 76.892456
    },
    {
        "Company": "Company Name 9",
        "Address": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet quaeque eruditi",
        "Telphone": "9714 883 7571",
        "Email": "Gma@emirates.net.ae",
        "Website": "www.emirates.net.au",
        "MarkerColor": 'pink',
        "Type": "MINING",
        "Location": "Middle East",
        "latitude": -5.856407,
        "longitude": 20.247047
    },
    {
        "Company": "Company Name 10",
        "Address": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet quaeque eruditi",
        "Telphone": "",
        "Email": "Gma@emirates.net.ae",
        "Website": "www.emirates.net.au",
        "MarkerColor": 'brown',
        "Type": "DISTRIBUTION OUTLET",
        "Location": "Asia Pacific",
        "latitude": -25.856407,
        "longitude": 120.247047
    },
    {
        "Company": "Company Name 11",
        "Address": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet quaeque eruditi",
        "Telphone": "",
        "Email": "Gma@emirates.net.ae",
        "Website": "www.emirates.net.au",
        "MarkerColor": 'yellow',
        "Type": "REPROCESSING PLANT",
        "Location": "Americas",
        "latitude": 55.856407,
        "longitude": -120.247047
    },
    {
        "Company": "Company Name 12",
        "Address": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet quaeque eruditi",
        "Telphone": "",
        "Email": "Gma@emirates.net.ae",
        "Website": "",
        "MarkerColor": 'pink',
        "Type": "MINING",
        "Location": "Americas",
        "latitude": 25.856407,
        "longitude": -100.247047
    },
    {
        "Company": "Company Name 13",
        "Address": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet quaeque eruditi",
        "Telphone": "",
        "Email": "Gma@emirates.net.ae",
        "Website": "",
        "MarkerColor": 'pink',
        "Type": "MINING",
        "Location": "Asia Pacific",
        "latitude": 4.062187,
        "longitude": 101.496645
    },
    {
        "Company": "Company Name 14",
        "Address": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet quaeque eruditi",
        "Telphone": "2233 65448 21",
        "Email": "Gma@emirates.net.ae",
        "Website": "",
        "MarkerColor": 'yellow',
        "Type": "REPROCESSING PLANT",
        "Location": "Asia Pacific",
        "latitude": 22.556300,
        "longitude": 113.916657
    },
    {
        "Company": "Company Name 15",
        "Address": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet quaeque eruditi",
        "Telphone": "2233 65448 21",
        "Email": "Gma@emirates.net.ae",
        "Website": "www.example.com",
        "MarkerColor": 'light-pink',
        "Type": "PROCESSING PLANT/MINE",
        "Location": "Americas",
        "latitude": 25.826347,
        "longitude": -80.207989
    },
    {
        "Company": "Company Name 16",
        "Address": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vel no congue quaeque eruditi",
        "Telphone": "",
        "Email": "Gma@emirates.net.ae",
        "Website": "",
        "MarkerColor": 'yellow',
        "Type": "REPROCESSING PLANT",
        "Location": "Europe",
        "latitude": 39.526054,
        "longitude": -3.892456
    }
];
// Solution when locations is provided:

const types = ['REPROCESSING PLANT','MINING','PROCESSING PLANT/MINE','DISTRIBUTION OUTLET'];
const locations = ['Europe']; // Just remove 'Europe' or add different location and test it!

let result = data.filter(d => types.some(t => d.Type === t) && locations.length > 0 ? locations.some(l => d.Location === l) : true);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: you answer not different op question.Both are doing same job. if `myfilter` is a single array or dual array .but matching condition is same

Comment: @prasad So, the solution ll be: let result = data.filter(d => myfilter.some(t => d.Type === t) || myfilter.some(l => d.Location === l))
As u said he needs || insted &&

Comment: I think so.but OP was not clear with his question.let wait for op update

Comment: this also doesnt work, because it should only show all data with types['REPROCESSING PLANT','MINING','PROCESSING PLANT/MINE','DISTRIBUTION OUTLET'] and  locations = ['Europe'] which is only 2 results

Comment: like this: https://jsfiddle.net/rpsb8buh/15/ btw 3 locations from europe. maybe i'm wrong.

Comment: correct its it should be 3 results my bad sorry, but with ur code
const types = ['REPROCESSING PLANT','MINING','PROCESSING PLANT/MINE','DISTRIBUTION OUTLET'];
const locations = ['Europe'];
i still get all restults

Comment: Can you provide final result inside fiddle? Put it inside comment. Thanks

Comment: you can find how the final result should be here,https://jsfiddle.net/rpsb8buh/18/
i put it in side variable with the current filter
Thanks

Comment: I found a solution. Check this fiddle and give me a feedback:
https://jsfiddle.net/rpsb8buh/20/

Comment: @user2135175 this is a clean solution: https://jsfiddle.net/rpsb8buh/21/

Comment: @KaramMurad Please mark answer as correct if that's a solution you are looking for. Thank you.